# To place values of object from key value pair in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-in-loop

I have an object

```
{
 "input":{
  "id": "7879",
  "inputType": "9876",
  "streamName": "870"
  },
 "transformation":{
   "id": "7",
   "dependencies": [
          "8i"
    ],
   "dropColumns": "hkj",
   "processor": "hgf"
 },
 "output": {
   "id": "v",
   "saveMode": "uyt",
   "dependentIds": [
        "h"
    ],
   "outPartition":[
        "hg"
    ]
 }
}
```

Basically every value leaving the key I have to put it in an array. So input, transformation, output values(which are objects) should be placed inside array.

Expected Output:

```
{
 "input": [
  {
  "id": "7879",
  "inputType": "9876",
  "streamName": "870"
  }
  ],
 "transformation":[
   {
   "id": "7",
   "dependencies": [
          "8i"
    ],
   "dropColumns": "hkj",
   "processor": "hgf"
 }
 ],
 "output":[
   {
   "id": "v",
   "saveMode": "uyt",
   "dependentIds": [
        "h"
    ],
   "outPartition":[
        "hg"
    ]
 }
 ]
}
```

I tried iterating using the for in loop but was not able to achieve the expected output how should I place the values(object) inside array

```
var arr = [];
for(key in obj){
  arr.push(Object.assign(obj[key],{name: key}))
}
```

Comment: Why `arr`? Why `Object.assign()`? Why `{name: key}`?

Comment: Why transform this structure at all? It is perfectly usable for any purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You mean this (although not sure why you would need this)?

```js
const input = {
 "input":{
  "id": "7879",
  "inputType": "9876",
  "streamName": "870"
  },
 "transformation":{
   "id": "7",
   "dependencies": [
          "8i"
    ],
   "dropColumns": "hkj",
   "processor": "hgf"
 },
 "output": {
   "id": "v",
   "saveMode": "uyt",
   "dependentIds": [
        "h"
    ],
   "outPartition":[
        "hg"
    ]
 }
}
Object.keys(input).forEach(key => input[key] = [input[key]] )
console.log(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the output of the object you provided, a simple implementation of looping the elements and creating the keys as arrays can be:

```
for(key in obj){
  obj[key] = [obj[key]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rebuild it using the reduce function if you want to do it immutable:

> The **reduce()** method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.
>
> More info see: [MDN Webdocs - reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const data = {
 "input":{
  "id": "7879",
  "inputType": "9876",
  "streamName": "870"
  },
 "transformation":{
   "id": "7",
   "dependencies": ["8i"],
   "dropColumns": "hkj",
   "processor": "hgf"
 },
 "output": {
   "id": "v",
   "saveMode": "uyt",
   "dependentIds": ["h"],
   "outPartition":["hg"]
 }
};

const customFormat = (data) => Object.keys(data).reduce((object, key) => {
    object[key] = [data[key]];
  return object
}, {});

console.log(customFormat(data));
```